# With Unity and Mecanim, how do I trigger an effect animation?

Tags: unity

We have a Mecanim animation. We'd like to play a particle effect on it at a certain frame in the animation.

Do we need to use an AnimationEvent and have it call a function that triggers the effect? Or is there some editor-only way to do it without script?

We're using Unity 5.3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively to SP's suggestion, you can also add events to the Mecanim animator now.  Take a look here:

[image]

Then you can script it in, if you prefer this method.  I have personally not used this feature yet, I just noticed it.  There doesn't seem to be much information in the docs about it yet.

Comment: It's a great feature. Used for footstep sound sync with animation for a side scroller.

Comment: It's a nice feature, but it makes your logic and animation prone to coupling.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the particle object as child to the main object and animate enable/disable the child in the animation tab. It's editor only.